# Brief on the concept of supernatural numbers

Tags: python, numbers

So I stumbled upon this problem on **Super Natural** **Numbers** on **HackerEarth**, the problem statement goes something like this -

You are given a number n.

A supernatural number is a number whose product of digits is equal to n, and in this number, there is no digit 1.

Count the number of supernatural numbers for a given n.

Input

Contains a single integer n, 1 <= n <= 100.

Output

Print the number of supernatural numbers.

*I need someone to brief me on this concept of Super Natural Number and how can I develop a code for it in Python3*

My Logic - So, as I come to understand, Super Natural Numbers are numbers that are equal to the product of two digits of another number. For example - Let's take 12, so 12 is equal to the product of 3 and 4 as in 34 or 43, or 2 and 6 as in 26 or 62.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The logic for Code - Let me take two lists and have all digits from 1 to 10 as their elements, If I multiply these two lists element-wise, I'll have a list of 100 elements. Then I can search that list for my initial input N and use a counter to find the number of super natural numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service nor a discussion forum. If you need to understand the problem specification, you should ask the person who posed it. If you need to understand how to do the math, then you have a math question, not a programming question, and should try a different website. If you have a question about how to write the code, then you need to *try to write the code* and then ask a *specific* question regarding your attempt, explaining *exactly what happened*, *exactly what was supposed to happen* and *how that is different*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hi Karl, I would firstly like to apologise if I didn't follow the appropriate decorum to ask a question on StackOverflow as I'm new to both programming and this platform. I couldn't come up with a logic for my question and thus thought of coming to this platform. I have added a few extra comments with my question if that helps.

Comment: What reason do you have to restrict the numbers to two digits? The problem statement certainly doesn't.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It was just a condition set to make the program run faster. I'm not very sure how much time it'll take since the program needs to run through a huge list of elements and iterate through them.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.PolkAlthogh I'm not very sure about that approach

Answer (score 0):

I like your logic, but I think you'll miss some.

E.g. 32 = 2x2x2x2x2, so the supernatural numbers of 32 would be 48, 84, 442, 424, 244, 2224, 2242, 2422, 4222 and 22222.

In your logic, you would only find 48 and 84.

Comment: But if I restrict my data set to numbers under 100 only, it may solve my problem don't you think? That way it'll be restricted to 84 only